# OpenEJB tries to bind a remote EJB twice

Tags: deployment, openejb

I am having a strange issue regarding OpenEJB and integration tests.
I am using Open EJB 4.5.1, JUnit 4.10 and Maven3 with surefire plugin 2.13
I start OpenEJB from my test doing:

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
```

It works (apparently) fine and deploys the EJB (*CentrosBeanFacade*) correctly, but after that it tries to bind it again, which causes the server to fail.

These are the interesting log parts:

First time --> [OK] :

```
DEBUG - bound ejb at name:       openejb/Deployment/CentrosBeanFacade/com.csc.health.xhis.arqtest.api.CentrosLogica, ref: org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.BusinessRemoteReference@6506fe2b
DEBUG - bound ejb at name: openejb/Deployment/CentrosBeanFacade/com.csc.health.xhis.arqtest.api.CentrosLogica!Remote, ref: org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.BusinessRemoteReference@6506fe2b
INFO - Jndi(name=CentrosBeanFacade) --> Ejb(deployment-id=CentrosBeanFacade)
INFO - Jndi(name=global/classpath.ear/test-ejb/CentrosBeanFacade!com.csc.health.xhis.arqtest.api.CentrosLogica) --> Ejb(deployment-id=CentrosBeanFacade)
INFO - Jndi(name=global/classpath.ear/test-ejb/CentrosBeanFacade) --> Ejb(deployment-id=CentrosBeanFacade)
```

But then it tries to deploy it a second time.

```
DEBUG - failed to bind ejb at name: openejb/Deployment/CentrosBeanFacade/com.csc.health.xhis.arqtest.api.CentrosLogica, ref: org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.BusinessRemoteReference@32f00d9a
ERROR - Jndi name could not be bound; it may be taken by another ejb.  Jndi(name=openejb/Deployment/CentrosBeanFacade/com.csc.health.xhis.arqtest.api.CentrosLogica!Remote)
```

The internal BusinessRemoteReference from EJB is a different object than the first time, so it **is** trying to deploy it a second time. But I have checked the classpath and the EJB is not included twice. If I execute a similar procedure but from a plain Java class, it also fails.

Any clues?